# Print single value if the records column have duplicates or same values (SQL & Laravel Livewire)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I would like to print records one time from an SQL if the records column have duplicates or same values. The table displays something like this: table name: admin

name    role    reg1    reg2    reg3    reg4

Jack    user    null    1   null    1

Jack    user    1   null    null    1

Jack    user    1   null    null    1

Check Condition; for print

If (reg1== null), print null
If (reg1== 1), print 1(one time)

If (reg2== null), print null (one time)
If (reg2== 1), print 1

If (reg3== null), print null (one time)
If (reg3== 1), (not fulfill)

If (reg4== null), (not fulfill)
If (reg4== 1), print 1 (one time)

Controller:

$admin=Admin::all()where(‘name’, $name)where(‘role’, $role);

I'm working in a Laravel livewire framework. Anyone can help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `distinct()` method of laravel.

`distinct()` method will fetch the unique value of given column.

[Please see the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#select-statements)